# Error when attempting .add/3 on NaiveDateTime

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir and am getting an error for a simple (so I thought) operation:

```
    d = NaiveDateTime.from_erl({{year, month, day}, {hours, minutes, seconds}}, {0, 0}, Calendar.ISO)
    NaiveDateTime.add(d, 20, :second)
```

This results in the following:

```
Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):

    def add(%{microsecond: {_, precision}, calendar: calendar} = naive_datetime, amount_to_add, unit) when is_integer(amount_to_add)
```

My code matches the examples I see elsewhere. I don't quite understand the error syntax. It's my understanding that `%{microsecond..` is a Map. Why the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it: be careful with your return values!

[NaiveDateTime.from_erl/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#from_erl/3) returns a *tuple*,  not simply a `NaiveDateTime` struct, so that's why `NaiveDateTime.add/3` is raising a `FunctionClauseError`.

Compare the following 2 outputs:

```
iex> d = NaiveDateTime.from_erl({{2021, 3, 30}, {10, 17, 0}}, {0, 0}, Calendar.ISO)
{:ok, ~N[2021-03-30 10:17:00]}
iex> d = NaiveDateTime.from_erl!({{2021, 3, 30}, {10, 17, 0}}, {0, 0}, Calendar.ISO)
~N[2021-03-30 10:17:00]
```

The first one returns a tuple containing the `NaiveDateTime` while the second returns only the `NaiveDateTime`.

In short, you can either use the `!` variant `NaiveDateTime.from_erl!/3` which returns a `NaiveDateTime` or raises on error, or you can match on the value returned from `NaiveDateTime.from_erl/3` like so:

```
iex> {:ok, d} = NaiveDateTime.from_erl({{2021, 3, 30}, {10, 17, 0}}, {0, 0}, Calendar.ISO)
# OR
iex> d = NaiveDateTime.from_erl!({{2021, 3, 30}, {10, 17, 0}}, {0, 0}, Calendar.ISO)
# then you may add:
iex> NaiveDateTime.add(d, 20, :second)
~N[2021-03-30 10:17:20]
```

Having a "regular" and a `!` variant of a function is common in Elixir and it's common to accidentally end up with a tuple when you only wanted the value.